# IdentityServer4 running on mobile device

Tags: mobile, identityserver4

I have this scenario ahead and I'm wondering if someone has already tried to run IdentityServer4 on mobile device since it supports .net core?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can. however IdentityServer4 is an ASP.NET Core middleware that relies on ASPNETCore.MVC which means it needs to be hosted. If you can figure out how to host a standard MVC application on the mobile device then you can add the IDS4 middleware to it.

You might need to jump through many hoops though but I have seen apps of phones that actually are "webservers" (AirDroid for example)